# Can we slow the advancement of Rheumatoid Arthritis (RA) with immunosuppressants?

Tags: autoimmune-disease, arthritis, immunosuppressant, rheumatology

Rheumatoid arthritis (RA) is a long-term autoimmune disorder that primarily affects joints ([Wikipedia, n.d.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheumatoid_arthritis)).

If the general cause is over activity of inflammatory cytokines ([Nalbant & Birlik, 2016](https://doi.org/10.5772/65893)), why do we just just manage RA with pain medications, steroids, non steroidal anti-inflammatory drugs (NSAIDs), and disease-modifying antirheumatic drugs (DMARDs) such as hydroxychloroquine and methotrexate?

Can we not deal with the cytokine over activity with immunosuppressants?

### References

Nalbant, S. & Birlik, A. M. (2016). Cytokines in Rheumatoid Arthritis (RA). In: Sakkas, L. (Ed.) *New Developments in the Pathogenesis of Rheumatoid Arthritis*. doi: [10.5772/65893](https://doi.org/10.5772/65893).

Wikipedia (n.d.). *Rheumatoid arthritis*. Retrieved from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheumatoid_arthritis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In treatment of rheumatoid arthritis, the following immunosuppressants, which are already in use, inhibit cytokines:

- Non-biologic DMARDs (Disease-modifying antirheumatic drugs): [methotrexate](https://academic.oup.com/rheumatology/article/42/10/1189/1784701), [leflunomide](https://www.jimmunol.org/content/165/10/5962), [hydroxychloroquine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3674253/), [sulfasalazine](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/pharmacology-toxicology-and-pharmaceutical-science/sulfasalazine), [cyclosporine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10685792), and [tacrolimus](https://academic.oup.com/rheumatology/article/43/8/992/1784457)
- [Biologic DMARDs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK507863/): adalimubab, anakinra, certolizumab, etanercept, golimubab, infliximab, etc.

Biologic DMARDs are not the first choice in treatment of RA because they:

- are expensive
- cannot be taken by mouth (because they contain antibodies, which are proteins)
- can have severe side effects (thrombosis, liver and kidney toxicity, demyelinating disorders...)
- increase the risk of infections (pneumonia, skin infections, the reactivation of tuberculosis or hepatitis B...)
- **usually do not induce remission,** unlike methotrexate and sulfasalazine ([Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/331715-treatment#d13))

[Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/331715-treatment#d13) (free registering required) and [John Hopkins Medicine](https://www.hopkinsarthritis.org/arthritis-info/rheumatoid-arthritis/ra-treatment/) cover drugs used in treatment of RA, including DMARDs, one by one in detail (mechanism of action, dosing, clinical effectiveness, side effects).

Most drugs mentioned here are included in [2015 American College of Rheumatology Guideline for the Treatment of Rheumatoid Arthritis](https://www.rheumatology.org/Portals/0/Files/ACR%202015%20RA%20Guideline.pdf).

Comment: I am a little confused when you say that biological DMARDs inhibit Janus kinases when I have just this afternoon been reading about [JAK inhibitors](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/rheumatoid-arthritis/treatment/) - separated from biological DMARDs - whereby JAK is [an acronym for the scientific term for a particular category of signalling molecules within the cell (Janus kinases)](https://www.nras.org.uk/jak-inhibitors-the-introduction-to-the-uk-market-of-the-first-jak-inhibitors-911). Are you aware of these and if so, what is the difference?

Comment: [This NHS page](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/rheumatoid-arthritis/treatment/) mentions biological DMARDs and JAKs separately, but [Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/331715-treatment#d13). [Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/monograph/tofacitinib-citrate.html) and [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/rheumatoid-arthritis/jak-inhibitors-rheumatoid-arthritis#1) consider JAKs a subgroup of DMARDs.

Comment: @ChrisRogers, most DMARDs, biologic and non-biologic, inhibit cytokines. JAKs belong to non-biologic DMARDs. Non-biologic DMARDs, including JAKs can be taken by mouth, while the biologic ones can't be.